# How can we add the Emoji in firebase using flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I am looking for a method where users can store the emoji of the keyboard into the firebasefirestore is there any library or function that you guys recommend to me.

Comment: Firestore does store most of the emojis. What is not working in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Emojis are technically just unicode characters with a specific code, you can find the full list of code [here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). You can save these unicode values on FirebaseFirestore, you do not need any library, flutter has everything out of the box!

You can later fetch these unicode and render them on Flutter using the text class by passing `\u` and the 4 letter hexadecimal in braces `{}` like the following:

```dart
Text("This is how you render unicode: \u{1f60e} ")
```

Below is a sample implementation:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text("This is how you render unicode: \u{1f60e} "), // This is the main part.
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw the different videos but none of them getting emoji from keyboard all of them getting emoji from package can you give me any reference

Comment: You can get emoji input directly from the keyboard (android/iOS/Web), it will be converted to Unicode automatically. You can find a sample code which I made: https://dartpad.dev/?id=af4ab9d07bfe0012aaf69abbe541b6b7&null_safety=true